# Why does Google Chrome have two PDF viewers?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I have Google Chrome Version 44.0.2403.130 (64-bit) for Linux and my OS is Lubuntu 14.04.

When I looked at the plugins page (chrome://plugins) after expanding details near the top right-hand side of the page, I notice that there are two PDF viewers.

[image: chrome://plugins]

What is the need for two PDF viewers?

Comment: If you have a link to that information, please post it as an answer along with a quote from the link in case the link dies. Thanks!